# Angular js pagination error

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying `angular js` pagination, I have done it but small issue on pagination  page numbers display. The error is shown in the below image.

[image]

Comment: Anyone , please suggest what needs to be done

Comment: Hi James, Please find the link for code https://jsfiddle.net/L5we5z1u/

Comment: Im able to resolve this issue. 
I observed that the libraries are loading twice that is why i'm getting this below warning on console .
WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.

Comment: Inserted the image referenced by the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im able to resolve this issue. I observed that the libraries are loading twice that is why i'm getting this below warning on console . WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.